# How to use COM INetCfg object through Python?

Tags: python, c++, com, comtypes

I am trying to enable/disable network binding interfaces in Windows using Python. See the picture below:

[image: Netwok binding interfaces dialog box]

I've understand that I have to utilize [INetCfg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547694%28VS.85%29.aspx) COM interfaces for this. And I believe [comtypes](https://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/) is the proper way to do this in Python. But still, I am pretty much new to comtypes.

The following page is [how to disable/enable IPv6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/17/how-to-enable-disable-ipv6-programmatically-in-windows-vista.aspx) in C. 
Does that C version can be easily converted to python using Comtypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick update : I have solved this. You will have to:

1. Generate TLB for INetCfg interface
2. Import it into Python using Comtypes
3. Create a COM object of INetCg instance
4. Acquire write lock
5. FindComponent for a given NIC
6. Enumarate protocol for that given NIC
7. Bind/Unbind protocol from given NIC
8. Apply changes
9. ReleaseLock

I will elaborate it as soon as I have time for this
You will have to get acquainted of comtypes to easily implement this.

Comment: Did you have this time ever since? ;)